# Most efficient way to store a big DNA sequence?

Tags: file-format

I want to pack a giant DNA sequence with an iOS app (about 3,000,000,000 base pairs). Each base pair can have a value `A`, `C`, `T` or `G`. Storing each base pair in one bytes would give a file of 3 GB, which is way too much. :)

Now I though of storing each base pair in two bits (four base pairs per octet), which gives a file of 750 MB. 750 MB is still way too much, even when compressed.

Are there any better file formats for efficiently storing giant base pairs on disk? In memory is not a problem as I read in chunks.

Comment: I think the 2 bits per nucleotide + compression is the best you can do. You might try different compression algorithms to test which ones give best compression ratio.

Comment: You should use compression algorithms, such as, for example, find sequences that repeat themselves and create a library, that will give them an ID, and instead of writing the whole sequence you'd just have the ID and the app will have to know how to decode that, though it's more power consuming it will save some memory.

Comment: Whatever it is you are trying to do is most likely not possible.  You will need to segment the data, use server processing, and/or stream the data.  But Timo is right.

Comment: When you say you "read in chunks" what do you mean exactly?  I'm thinking you will want to use some type of stream compression.  Or you could just compress the chunks on the fly.  Something like http://code.google.com/p/dna-compress or CTW-LZ stream encoding.

Comment: @user120242 with "reading in chunks" is mean I stream the data from disk in chunks of e.g. 64 octets and parse that. The app will only load more chunks when they are needed, and free chunks from memory when they aren't needed anymore. This is due to the fact I want to show them to the user, but you cannot fit 3,000,000,000 base pairs on such a small screen all at once.

Answer (score 10):

I think you'll have to use two bits per base pair, plus implement compression as described in [this paper](http://www.csjournals.com/IJITKM/PDF%203-1/42.pdf).

"DNA sequences... are not random; they contain
repeating sections, palindromes, and other features that
could be represented by fewer bits than is required to spell
out the complete sequence in binary...

With the proposed algorithm, sequence will be compressed by 75%
irrespective of the number of repeated or non-repeated
patterns within the sequence."

DNA Compression Using Hash Based Data Structure, International Journal of Information Technology and Knowledge Management
July-December 2010, Volume 2, No. 2, pp. 383-386.

Edit: There is a program called GenCompress which claims to compress DNA sequences efficiently:

http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~chenxin/GenCompress/

Edit: See also [this question](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/8745/which-dna-compression-algorithms-are-actually-used) on BioStar.

Comment: I read the paper (diagonally) and if I understood correctly, they just encode (hash) the 4-letter chunks as separate letters. It can be beneficial in databases as you can index the sequences better. But in this case, however, using 2 bits instead of 8 gives you exactly same win. Plus if you apply some basic compression algo on this 2-bit token sequences, you should get better results than described in the paper.

Comment: @Timo: From the paper: "The compression of DNA sequences is considered as one
of the most challenging tasks in the field of data
compression... Standard compression algorithms are not
able to compress DNA sequences."

Comment: @Luke Girvin. Also from paper: "Standard text compression algorithm cannot compress DNA sequences ..", well, this is not exactly true. It is hard to compress random data, which DNA sequences are not. Anyway, I just wanted to point out that it seems that their algorithm operates on 8-bit char values and their procedure is implemented in a database server. As for an IPhone app, simply using 2-bits instead of 8 will give similar win. I apologize, if I misinterpret the paper.

Comment: If GenCompress open-source? I can't seem to find the source code.

Comment: @Timo, I think you're misreading the paper. Anyway, the point is that it is possible to compress DNA sequences, but it is a difficult and complicated problem, and 'standard' compression algorithms are not particularly effective.

Comment: @WTP, I don't think so, I can't find the source either.

Comment: DNACompress is open source: http://monod.uwaterloo.ca/downloads/dnacompress/ it's java so you will have to port it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having a complex solution, take a look at [this paper](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/early/2011/03/29/gr.114819.110.full.pdf) or [this paper](http://www.irb.hr/hr/home/ristov/papers/ristov_IS03.pdf/) or even [this one which is more detailed](http://genome.cshlp.org/content/21/5/734.full).

But I think you need to specify better what you're dealing with. Some specifics applications can lead do diferent storage. For example, the last paper I cited deals with lossy compression of DNA...

Answer (score 1):

Base pairs always **pair** up, so you should only have to store one side of the strand.  Now, I doubt that this works if there are certain mutations in the DNA (like a di-Thiamine bond) that cause the opposite strand to not be the exact opposite of the stored strand.  Beyond that, I don't think you have many options other than to compress it somehow. But, then again, I'm not a bioinformatics guy, so there might be some pretty sophisticated ways to store a bunch of DNA in a small space.  Another idea if it's an iOS app is just putting a reader on the device and reading the sequence from a web service.

Comment: Of course, I only store one side of the base-pair, but this would still give 3,000,000 items to store.

Answer (score 1):

Use a diff from a reference genome.  From the size (3Gbp) that you post, it looks like you want to include a full human sequences.  Since sequences don't differ too much from person to person, you should be able to compress massively by storing only a diff.

Could help a lot.  Unless your goal is to store the reference sequence itself.  Then you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

consider this, how many different combinations can you get? out of 4 (i think its about 16 )

actg = 1
atcg = 2
atgc = 3 and so on, so that

you can create an array like [1,2,3] then you can go one step further,

check if 1 is follow by 2, convert 12 to a, 13 = b and so on... 
if I understand DNA a bit it means that you cannot get a certain value

as a must be match with c, and t with g or something like that which reduces your options,
so basically you can look for a sequence and give it a something you can also convert back...

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into a 3d space-filling curve. A 3d sfc reduces the 3d complexity to a 1d complexity. It's a little bit like n octree or a r-tree. If you can store your full dna in a sfc you can look for similar tiles in the tree although a sfc is most likely to use with lossy compression. Maybe you can use a block-sorting algorithm like the bwt if you know the size of the tiles and then try an entropy compression like a huffman compression or a golomb code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tools like MFCompress, Deliminate,Comrad.These tools provides entropy less than 2.That is for storing each symbol it will take less than 2 bits