# Efficiently storing DNA base-pair data in RAM?

Tags: c++, memory

Very related to this question:
[Most efficient way to store a big DNA sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493889/most-efficient-way-to-store-a-big-dna-sequence)
and this one:
[Declaring a new data type for DNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399610/declaring-a-new-data-type-for-dna)

I'd like to find a way to efficiently store long sets of the characters ACTG without wasting an entire byte for each value, when it should only require 2 bits.
However, I don't see any descriptions in the responses regarding how to go about storing 2-bit data in C++, or Java or any language for that matter, although I figure C++ should be the ideal language for it.

So my question is this, what is the syntax to properly create a conveniently usable 2-bit data type? I assume some sort of structure is going to need to be made to fill byte-sized(lol) chunks of data, but I'm not really certain.

I'd be very interested in knowing if such a thing is possible in other languages as well, such as Javascript or Perl, but mostly how you go about it in C++.

Example code would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Waaaaaay too broad, mate. Even if you narrow it down to a single language, I'm not sure if this question is suitable for SO.

Comment: I'm getting very tired of having every question I post on SO get downvoted, what has happened to this community? I think it's a very reasonable question, how do you create a 2-bit structure in C++? Other languages are simply bonus.

Comment: Std::bitset perhaps. Stores bits and might be a good starting point

Comment: Other languages are completely irrelevant to your main question, then.

Comment: Perhaps stick to one language is a good idea

Comment: Thank you Ed, I'll check it out.

Other languages are fairly relevant since when dealing with this type of problem I often would prefer to do it in a higher-level language than C++, so I'm interested in knowing if that is possible.

Comment: Long answer short - a single char can store 4 sequences.  You can do the bit twiddling yourself in a char array (C Style), or use a bitset and hope that it does an efficient job of things.  Or, you could just compress the whole ACTG char array with a compressor of your choice if storage is the only concern.  Once you store this info, what do you plan to do with it?  There is a cost in packing bits this way that makes data manipulation later on a bit more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you encode the data in a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and store the bitsets in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  You can just code a DNA pair in the bitset and waste four bits per element in the vector or you could code 2 DNA pairs in each bitset and then you have perfect storage.

Comment: Do you know how much processing/structure overhead would I accumulate trying to store two pairs in each vector?

Comment: @Eckster You wouldn't be storing 2 pairs in each vector.  you would be storing 2 pairs in each bitset and then all of the bitsets would be stored in a single vector.

Comment: I admit that I'm not very good at low-level C++(hence asking about other languages), pointers are about as complex as I typically deal with, is there any way you could show me an example of what this would look like in use, as in setting up an array of the  2-bit structures, filling it with data, and then reading it out?

Comment: @Eckster There are different ways you could do it.  [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5e46d63c8e726cc) is a very naive approach.